# DialogFlow promotions failing

Tags: dialogflow-es

In the last 24 hours I've attempted promotions twice now for a single DialogFlow agent, when I show "All versions" from the Environments tab, the two most recent deployments are still showing a status of "Deploying".

I've tried to repromote.

There is no code involved.

When I request the promotion of a trained agent, I expect the promotion to complete; in this case, the promotion "appears" to complete successfully, however, when I check the "All versions" page, it shows both of the last two promotions as still "Deploying".

[Long running deployments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XASv.png)

Comment: Following, I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: same issue is happening to me since yesterday.